# Erro ao esconder menu com base em permissões do usuário

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Olá, eu possuía um método para controlar acesso aos menus, com base nas permissões. Porém do nada parou de funcionar e eu recebo o erro:
"Não é possível fazer associação em tempo de execução em uma referência nula"

Não sei o que foi alterado para isso acontecer.

Segue o código onde eu faço a comparação:

No meu model eu possuo um ENUM, com os possíveis perfis:

```
public enum Perfil
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Permissão para Envio, Listagem e Visualização dos arquivos.
    /// </summary>
    FUNCIONARIO,

    /// <summary>
    /// Permissão para Envio, Listagem, Visualização, Análise e Sincronização dos arquivos.
    /// </summary>
    SERVIDOR,

    /// <summary>
    /// Todas as permissões, inclusive inclusão de novos usuários para acesso ao sistema.
    /// </summary>
    ADMINISTRADOR
}
```

E no model eu possuo um atributo com o perfil de cada usuário:

```
 [Display(Name = "Perfil")]
    public string sPerfil { get; set; }
```

Na minha classe de autenticação, eu possuo o seguinte código, para ver se o usuário está ou não com permissão:

```
public class CustomAutenticacaoAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    public IAutenticacaoProvider autenticacaoProvider { get; set; }

    private string msgErro;

    private string[] perfilComPermissao;

    public CustomAutenticacaoAttribute(Perfil[] perfil)
    {
        perfilComPermissao = new string[perfil.Length];

        for (int x = 0; x < perfil.Length; x++)
        {
            perfilComPermissao.SetValue(perfil[x].ToString(), x);
        }
    }


    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!autenticacaoProvider.Autenticado)
        {
            msgErro = "Você precisa estar autenticado para acessar essa página";
            return false;
        }
        if (perfilComPermissao.Length > 0 && !perfilComPermissao.Contains<string>(autenticacaoProvider.UsuarioAutenticado.Perfil))
        {
            msgErro = "Você não tem permissão para acessar essa página com suas credenciais.";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        filterContext.Controller.TempData["Mensagem"] = msgErro;


    }
}
```

}

E na view eu so faço a seguinte marcação:

```
 @if (ViewBag.UsuarioAutenticado.Perfil.Equals(PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Perfil.FUNCIONARIO.ToString())
                             || (ViewBag.UsuarioAutenticado.Perfil.Equals(PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Perfil.ADMINISTRADOR.ToString())))
                        {
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Todos", "Index", "Requerimento")</li>
                        }
```

Estava funcionando perfeitamente, porém fiz alguma alteração no código, em meus controllers, e não sei o que pode ter causado isso.
Alguém saberia como me ajudar?

Comment: Use o Debug do Visual Studio e insira Breakpoints em seus métodos para identificar em qual trecho de código ocorre o erro. Assim ficará mais fácil ajudá-lo.

Comment: Olhei o Debug, e avisava que estava nulo. Tratei esse erro, porém o erro persistiu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troquei a autenticação da View de:

```
 @if (ViewBag.UsuarioAutenticado.Perfil.Equals(PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Perfil.FUNCIONARIO.ToString())
                         || (ViewBag.UsuarioAutenticado.Perfil.Equals(PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Perfil.ADMINISTRADOR.ToString())))
                    {
```

Por:

```
 @if (ViewBag.Perfil == "ADMINISTRADOR" || ViewBag.Perfil == "FUNCIONARIO")
                        {
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Todos", "Index", "Requerimento")</li>
                        }
```

E funcionou corretamente. Não sei se essa é a melhor forma, ou se é forma correta, porém está funcionando.